# Как сделать самый простой таймер отсчета времени?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Я ещё только-только начал изучать Javascript, и не понимаю его синтаксис, операторы и т. д. Но мне очень  хочеться сделать самый простой таймер обратного отчета времени, для которого не нужны глубокие познания в языках программирования! Если хотите помочь, то пишите коды!!!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы Вам помогли, наилучшим решением будет попросить помощи, а не ставить условия.

Comment: По вопросу видно, что вы а) не читали правила StackOverflow б) не пытались разобраться в вопросе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C наступающим! Вот рабочий пример с комментариями для обучения.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() // дожидаемся загрузки страницы
    {
        initializeTimer(); // вызываем функцию инициализации таймера
    }


    function initializeTimer() {
        var endDate = new Date(2020,9,31,8,31); // получаем дату истечения таймера
        var currentDate = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату
        var seconds = (endDate-currentDate) / 1000; // определяем количество секунд до истечения таймера
        if (seconds > 0) { // проверка - истекла ли дата обратного отсчета
            var minutes = seconds/60; // определяем количество минут до истечения таймера
            var hours = minutes/60; // определяем количество часов до истечения таймера
            minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60; // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе
            hours = Math.floor(hours); // целое количество часов до истечения таймера
            seconds = Math.floor((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60); // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся секунд в текущей минуте
            minutes = Math.floor(minutes); // округляем до целого кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе

            setTimePage(hours,minutes,seconds); // выставляем начальные значения таймера

            function secOut() {
                if (seconds == 0) { // если секунду закончились то
                    if (minutes == 0) { // если минуты закончились то
                        if (hours == 0) { // если часы закончились то
                            showMessage(timerId); // выводим сообщение об окончании отсчета
                        }
                        else {
                            hours--; // уменьшаем кол-во часов
                            minutes = 59; // обновляем минуты
                            seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        minutes--; // уменьшаем кол-во минут
                        seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
                    }
                }
                else {
                    seconds--; // уменьшаем кол-во секунд
                }
                setTimePage(hours,minutes,seconds); // обновляем значения таймера на странице
            }
            timerId = setInterval(secOut, 1000) // устанавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
        }
        else {
            alert("Установленная дата уже прошла");
        }
    }

    function setTimePage(h,m,s) { // функция выставления таймера на странице
        var element = document.getElementById("timer"); // находим элемент с id = timer
        element.innerHTML = "Часы:"+h+"<br>Минуты:"+m+"<br>Секунды:"+s; // выставляем новые значения таймеру на странице
    }

    function showMessage(timerId) { // функция, вызываемая по истечению времени
        alert("Время истекло!");
        clearInterval(timerId); // останавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
    }
</script>

<div id="timer">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, тебя тоже с наступающим новым годом!

Comment: Как тут одблагододить за ответ?

Comment: Спасибо. Стрелочку вверх около ответа, но это не обязательно. Главная задача помочь ) Удачи Вам в обучении.